# Raster stacking with naturally ordered layers gives ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate?

Tags: python, gdal, numpy

I need to create a multiple bands .tiff file, also known as rasters stack.
I ordered the files to be stacked (from the folder) using natsort and it works.

How to use the method 'os.walk' with the ordered list (ord_list), because
I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpAP_F30.py", line 20, in <module>
    stackRast = np.dstack(rasters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py", line 368, in dstack
    return _nx.concatenate([atleast_3d(_m) for _m in tup], 2)
ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate
```

I wrote my script doing **copy/paste** of some stuff in the net, I'm not skilled in Python yet.

```
import os
import natsort
import sys
import numpy as np
import gdal
import gdalnumeric as gd
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter

rasters = list()

# natural sorting
sourceDir = "/home/giacomo/Desktop/eee/"
unord_list = set(os.listdir(sourceDir))
ord_list = ('\n'.join(natsort.natsorted(unord_list)))

# layer stacking
for folder, subs, files in os.walk(ord_list):
    for filename in files:
        aSrc = gd.LoadFile(os.path.join(folder,filename))
        rasters.append(aSrc)

stackRast = np.dstack(rasters)
```

How can I avoid getting this error?

Comment: Is the maximum number of rasters to stack  4 or it's variable?

Comment: I see a problem in the order of bands. I'm afraid that the ordering of **natsort** was not good (seems that bands to stack are not adjacent). So, I need a complete series of your bands to stack for cracking the algorithm. Probably you need to use **re** (regular expressions) python module instead **natsort**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution. Just this; @Xunilk

```
import os
import natsort

sourceDir = "/home/giacomo/Desktop/eee/"
unord_list = set(os.listdir(sourceDir))

ord_list = []
dd = ""
namestack = "prova.tif"

for folder, subs, files in os.walk(sourceDir):
    for filename in files:
        base_name, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if(extension == ".tif"):
            ord_list.append(filename)

ord_list = natsort.natsorted(ord_list)

n = len(ord_list)

for i in range(0, n, 1):
    band = ord_list[i]        
    aa = sourceDir + band
    dd = dd + aa + " " 

cmd = "gdal_merge.py -separate -o" + " "+ sourceDir + namestack + " " 
+ dd
os.system(cmd)
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because **sourceDir** is a directory and **unord_list** is precisely a list (no a directory). Command **os.walk(ord_list)** cannot work in this context. You need to use **ord_list** only as criterion for matching the list of rasters to be stacked. By the way, for stacking your rasters you can use **gdal_merge.py** with **-separate** parameter. It's straightforward.

To test my approach, I modified your code to force my rasters **b3_ref.tif** and **b4_ref.tif** (in my **sourceDir**) to stack among 174 *tif files. You should modified it with your own criterion.

```
import os
import natsort

sourceDir = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/"
unord_list = set(os.listdir(sourceDir))
ord_list = []

for folder, subs, files in os.walk(sourceDir):
    for filename in files:
        base_name, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if(extension == ".tif"):
            ord_list.append(filename)

ord_list = natsort.natsorted(ord_list)

n = len(ord_list)

for i in range(1, n, 2): #warning: iterator begins from 1 to match
                         #2 layers in my example
    try:
        b1 = ord_list[i] 
        b2 = ord_list[i+1]
        output = "stack_" + b1[:-4] + "_" + b2[:-4] + ".tif"
        if b1 == 'b3_ref.tif' and b2 == 'b4_ref.tif':
            cmd = 'gdal_merge.py -separate -o ' + sourceDir + output + ' ' + sourceDir + b1 + ' ' + sourceDir + b2
            os.system(cmd)
            print "done"
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

After running the code at the Python Console of QGIS, the stacked layer was named as **stack_b3_ref_b4_ref.tif** and it looks like as in next image. I used Value Tool plugin to corroborate that it's a stacked raster and its values are coincident with original rasters.

[image]

Comment: Dear xunilk, thank you for your help, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Nothing happens. I don't know why

Comment: Obviously, its works with my criteria. You need to establish your own stacking criteria. To find out yours, please, comment all lines after for i in range(1, n, 2) (including this one), run the script and put in your question an extract of obtained ord_list.

Comment: How  many bands do you want to stack? In my case two bands was only an example.

Comment: Dear Xunilk, your scripts works, but doesn't properly solve my problem. I don't want n stacks with two bands, but only one stack with n bands. I modified your script and i will report only the last part. 

`n = len(ord_list)

for i in range(0, n, 1):
    band = ord_list[i]        
    a = sourceDir + band    
    a.append(b)

    cmd = "gdal_merge.py -separate -o " + sourceDir + namestack + " " + ddd + "
    os.system(cmd)` I receive an error  `a.append(b)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'`

Comment: I understood but, I need  an extract of your **ord_list** to see the structure of your file rasters.

Comment: I apologize, you're right. Unfortunatelly the ord_list is very long. Here is an extract  `['2_S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20160101T174916_20160101T174941_009304_00D70A_AAFB__OSGB_VH.tif', '3_S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20160110T061404_20160110T061458_009428_00DA93_B5C5__OSGB_VH.tif', '4_S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20160113T174921_20160113T174946_009479_00DC0B_B660__OSGB_VH.tif'] `

Comment: Please, edit your question and put in it an extract of obtained **ord_list** with at least two cycles of raster to stack. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, this is my order_list with 4 images in my folder: `>>> print (ord_list)
['2_S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20160101T174916_20160101T174941_009304_00D70A_AAFB__OSGB_VH
.tif', '3_S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20160110T061404_20160110T061458_009428_00DA93_B5C5__O
SGB_VH.tif', '4_S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20160113T174921_20160113T174946_009479_00DC0B_B
660__OSGB_VH.tif', '5_S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20160125T174915_20160125T174940_009654_00
E129_4FAF__OSGB_VH.tif']`. Are you looking for this? Thank you

Comment: The number of rasters is variable. I would like to stack all the rasters in a folder. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55388/discussion-between-ilfonta-and-xunilk).